# Unexpected size after decompressing with gzip

Tags: postgresql, gzip, ubuntu-20.04

I am decompressing database, which size should be more than 29-30GB, but sometimes the end result is lower than 23GB, which is not expected. How can I search for logs or implement error handler?

```
#!/bin/bash
filePath="/home/user/theFile"
gzip -d $filePath
```

Doing this on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: gzip logs to its stderr.

Comment: What did gzip say?

Comment: The problem was different versions between the machines.